# Add active class to nav bar

Tags: javascript

I'm sort of new to this, so please forgive me asking, but I'm using a slightly modified bootstrap navbar, and had the active class being properly assigned untill recently, but for some reason it stoped working with the last changes I made... (tried to revert it to see what screwed it up, to no avail...)
Could some gentle soul enlighten me on how to make it work as it should?

Cheers!
T.F.

```
    view:

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ACAC</a>
            </div>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>">INÍCIO<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>noticias">NOTÍCIAS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>projecto">PROJECTO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>actividades">ACTIVIDADES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>galeria">GALERIA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>contactos">CONTACTOS</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <a href="#" class="lnklang">EN</a>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    .....
        <script>
    $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
       $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
       $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You have two elements that use the `.nav` class, so that may be messing up the selectors. Try removing the one you aren't testing, and see if the other one starts working again.

Comment: learn to use `git` and this will never happen again

Comment: Can you let us know what you expect to happen? (what element should have class `active` after the click).

Comment: @ShaneAbramMendez: I'm still fairly new to it, so I dont always remember about it, but point made. It was working the last time I saved it with git, just that it was over 24h ago, so I was trying to get this fixed without having to revert all the changes I made since then.

Comment: @Damon: any of the <li> between:

'<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
....
</ul>'

on click.
Atm it seems to me it's assigning and then removing the active class

Comment: If it was working on your last commit you can use `git stash` that will revert you to your last commit and `stash` the changes. that way you can at least see what you changed. When you are ready to go back to your changes run `git stash apply`

Comment: @forgivenson: tried, didnt work

Comment: Do you see any errors in developer tools in chrome when you click a link?

Comment: @Sico: you mean the console? If so, there wasnt any.
Anyway, I've followed ShaneAbramMendez hint and did a git stash thingy majiggy, and got it working again.
Gonna try and remake all todays work and see if I dont screw it up again.

Cheers all!
T.F.

Comment: @ShaneAbramMendez - or at least, learn to use a version control system, of which git is merely the current flavour of the month.

Comment: @enhzflep you are a truly seasoned software engineer. +1

Comment: So you click a link and the page refreshes. What is resetting the active class when the page reloads?

Comment: @sico: That's probably it.... after clicking a link I load the template from another controller, loading the original html for the header again, with the active class set to the first link.
any way to go around that?

PS: and I'm sorry for my lack of insight, otherwise I'd have asked the question differently...

Comment: if its an ajax load use preventDefault or use @Kaisers answer?

Comment: @sico: i'm gonna research what Kaiser said and see if it works.
Cheers,
T.F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on the menu page navigates to new page. Active menu is changed but when the page is reloaded to new page it is reset to default.

You can check the page on document.ready and set the menu active for that page -

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("noticias") > -1) {
     $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
     $('.nav a[href$="http://www.base_url.com/notice"]').parent().addClass("active");
}
```

change http://www.base_url.com/ to your actual base url.

Comment: I'm gonna research what you said and see how to implement it.
Thanks for your answer!
Cheers,
T.F.

Comment: @Kaiser: works just fine if inserted into the view instead of the footer include as I had it! Thanks!

Comment: @ShaneAbramMendez: he did, but I got what he meant.
Thanks for your time!
Cheers!
T.F.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code with `hrefs` removed and `li` content changed
none of my edits changed how you code works, and it seems to work fine

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ACAC</a>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        
        <li class="active"><a>One</a></li>
        <li><a>Two</a></li>
        <li><a>Three</a></li>
        <li><a>Four</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a href="#" class="lnklang">EN</a>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
.....
<script>
  $(".nav a").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
</script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yea, the hrefs seem to be the problem.
I had just tried adding the links back, after the git stash thingy, and it stop working again.
Any idea on how to go around that?

Comment: What does echo base_url() give you

Comment: @Sico: 'http ://acac/'
I'm using CI, that's what I have set as base_url on the config file
(extra space after the http on purpose, so to show it)

Comment: Without hrefs the page doesn't navigate so the jquery works

Comment: @Sico: yea, lack of insight from my part. It makes perfect sense.
Got it working following Kaizers suggestion.
Thanks for all!
Cheers,
T.F.

Comment: Post the working code? So people with your problem know how to fix it